# SFMC Triggered send using API errors and questions

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Question #1
Configuration for using ExactTarget – Triggered Send
We are planning to use ExactTarget – Triggered Send capability for its Member Registration Process. What is the Recommended configuration required to use ExactTarget – Triggered Send configuration?
Application Sever, Platform, version, connectivity, etc.

Question #2
When we deployed the Triggered Send API's on WebSphere Application Server (WAS) we are facing the following error are on the server.

We are working on creating a Web Service (WebSphere Runtime 8.0.0.9) where we are trying to invoke triggered Send via a CXF client.

While testing the client via JUnit, the installation of the client proxy works fine. However, when the same code is execute via WebSphere Server, it fails with incompatibility errors

The following troubleshooting options were tried in WebSphere Environment as well -

1. Changing the class loader of WAS server to Parent load last
2. Passing JVM arugment -Dcom.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true
3. Setting DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true in the WAR MANIFEST.MF

Question #3
Do does SFMC provide a SDK based on Java/Axis2 which we can use for Triggered Send?